# Install private gitlab package with specific version

Tags: python, pip, gitlab, pypi, python-poetry

I have private gitlab package. His current version == 0.2.15

I am build and publish package with poetry. Always I install package as

`pip install sdk --index-url https://__token__:<token>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/pypi/simple`

I need to install specific version of package (0.2.13 f.e.). How can I do it? I tried with `@0.2.13` and `#0.2.13`. It's not work.

Comment: Try `pip install sdk==0.2.13 --index-url https://__token__:<token>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/pypi/simple`

Comment: Happy it helped. Please accept my answer since it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package version is specified with `==`.

```bash
pip install sdk==0.2.13 \
    --index-url 'https://__token__:<token>@gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/pypi/simple'
```